# KMP moko-shared resources xcframework bundle with identifier MR not found

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I faced with the problem that iOs app can't get shared String resource by provided ID. Ios and kmp module are in different repositories

1. I followed the configuration in README of the lib. https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources. Seems like there are no additional steps for xcframeworks.
2. I build **dynamic** (isStatic = false) framework

```
 listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = SHARE_BINARY_NAME
            export(libs.moko.shared.resources)
        }
    }
```

3. Locally, I build framework assembleXCFramework
4. Distribute framework by kmmbridge plugin
5. Tried to get string res (running on simulator):
   `Strings().get(SharedRes.strings().string_resId)`

In the built framework I can see `shared.bundle` with generated strings.

[Also I can see them in generated files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv06V.png)

as the result I receive exception:
`kotlin.IllegalArgumentException: bundle with identifier com.example.shared.MR not found`